# UIToolbar doesn't appear with grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have a UIViewController that contains a grouped UITableView and a UIToolbar (at the very top) which I have created in Interface Builder.

I am presenting this viewcontroller modally.

When I run the application in the simulator the UIToolbar does not appear. I'm not exactly sure why?

Comment: Does the tableview cover it, perhaps?

Comment: No I made sure that the tableview is below the toolbar

Comment: Is there a navigation bar? This may be covering the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the view outlet connected to the tableview. it should be connected to the view since it is a UIViewController